# What's the recipe for running mvn integration-test instead of mvn test with Travis?

Tags: maven, travis-ci

The travis doc seems to lack an example of how to simply change the 'default test command' from `mvn test` to `mvn verify` to run the full integration test lifecycle.  Could someone please provide the .travis.yml incantation for this purpose?

Comment: https://github.com/phillord/hermit-maven/blob/master/.travis.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply provide the `script` property with the right value in your *travis* configuration file (*.travis.yml*):

```
## Run Integration tests
script: "mvn test && mvn verify"
```

Answer (score 14):

tmarwen's answer is correct, but it will run your unit tests twice (the mvn "verify" phase already includes the "test" phase) as explained in the documentation for [Maven - Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

You can simply use (it will run both unit tests and integration tests, once each). It will work just as well, but faster (no need to delete /target folder, recompile all the code, and re-run unit tests a second time):

> script: "mvn verify"